# Internet Explorer and Zones on a website with multiple sources

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-security

If I add a site to the trusted sites zone and it has scripts from sites in the internet zone, how will it treat content loaded from sites in different zones?

Will it treat everything on the page as if it is from the less trusted zone? Or the more trusted zone? Or will the scripts be treated on a per-domain basis?

I ask because I have a site that needs a particular script to be trusted but has resources from many other websites.

Comment: Could you merge the external scripts into a single script at build time that you can then host in the correct zone?

Comment: No, the only part of the process we can control are the zones - the files and the hosting locations are out of our control. That would be the best solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts seem to be treated on a per-domain basis. So scripts from each domain are blocked or run depending on which zone they are in.

I wrote a test page. rr() and qq() both are the same as the inline script. By moving domains between zones it's easy to see that some get blocked and some don't.

```
<html>
    <!-- Put yourjavascript.com temporarily into the untrusted zone -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yourjavascript.com/51158106415/scare.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <p id="one">Inline Script <span>Blocked</span></p>
    <p id="two">Local Script <span>Blocked</span></p>
    <p id="three">Trusted Script <span>Blocked</span></p>
    <p id="four">Untrusted Script <span>Blocked</span></p>
    <script>
    //inline
        document.getElementById('one').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = "Allowed";
    </script>
    <script>
    //local
        rr();
    </script>
    <script>
        //trusted
        $('#three span').html("Allowed");
    </script>
    <script>
        //untrusted
        qq();
    </script>
</html>
```